# Can you include a timeout option in a helm test template file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I know it's possible to change the timeout option when performing `helm test` from the command line by using the `--timeout` flag on the command line.

Is there a way to specify that in the template file instead?

Comment: What is purpose of doing such thing ?

Comment: @Malgorzata Using helm test from a system where I don't have command line access. In that case being able to specify it in the template file would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tests are specified as `Job`s instead of `Pod`s, a deadline can be specified in the `JobSpec` by setting the `activeDeadlineSeconds` field.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ include "helm-test-timeout.fullname" . }}-test-timeout"
  labels:
{{ include "helm-test-timeout.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": test-success
spec:
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 30
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      # The nginx container will just launch and wait
      # and cause the test to time out
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
      restartPolicy: Never
```

However, this deadline cannot be extended with the `--timeout` flag to `helm test`.